# DeviceMotion data from ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, core-motion

I want to get a `CoreMotion` data from `ARKit` - I need `DeviceMotion` `attitude` and `gravity`. Is there any way to get these values? I need them to calculate a compass direction directly from `ARKit` session, instead of using `CLLocationManager`.